A movie where a vampire taunts his friend in an adjacent jail cell while crawling through a vent
There was a scene from a movie where a vampire (I think) was in a jail cell next to his friend and squeezed into the vent between the two cells. As he was getting closer to his friend, he taunted him as he crawled. What was this movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Bloodrayne features a lot of jail cells and shackles.

Voting to leave this question open. The details provided don’t seem overly vague to me. A vampire in a jail cell, crawling through a vent while taunting a friend. It seems like a pretty specific and unique scenario. I’d argue it’s enough to identify a specific show.
